# How do I use/set up this LED light strip?

Tags: led, led-strip

I stumbled upon this long strip of LED lights in my house and was hoping to set them up but have no idea how to. I am pretty sure they are made by Adafruit but not entirely sure. They look pretty similar to these:

- https://www.adafruit.com/product/1138?length=2 and
- https://www.adafruit.com/product/2842?length=1

If someone could point me in the direction of how to set these up that would be great. Ideally, I could just buy something to plug these into that came with a remote to control the color but understand that it might require some parts. I've attached photos of the attachments at each end of the strip and of the lights themselves. Please help if you can, I have no idea what I am doing!

Photos:

[image: Connector]

[image: Connector, end-on view]

[image: LED Strip]

Comment: If you don't want to program using a microcontroller, you can buy LED controllers. Search for "ws2812 controller" on Amazon. Most have a 3-pin connector instead of the 2-pin in your pictures.

Answer (score 1):

The strip has effectively three wires:

1. **5V**
2. **Data** (DIN)
3. **GND** (two black wires; one for the power supply and one for the controller)

The individual LEDs are almost certainly a variant of the [WS2812 driver](http://www.world-semi.com/solution/list-4-1.html), which are commonly used in Adafruit's "NeoPixel" product lines.

Most projects that use these employ a microcontroller to generate and send color data. [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) is probably the most common, though you could use any platform that can meet the timing requirements.

Adafruit has a collection of very comprehensive tutorials about how to drive these. Start with their [NeoPixel Uberguide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide).